# Reference .dlls on runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reference

If you observe the following picture, my 'RSR.exe' application runs perfectly fine as the two .dlls are located on the same file-path; however, if those 2 .dlls are not located on the same file path/directory as the RSR.exe, it will result in a crash/'program has stopped working'.

[image: READ ABOVE COMMENT]

Here is the following piece of code I am trying to use with no success.

```
public static MainForm _mainForm;

    static string subPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RSR";

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(subPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\RSR\\MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.dll", Properties.Resources.MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor);

                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\RSR\\WindowsFormsAero.dll", Properties.Resources.WindowsFormsAero);
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\RSR\\MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.dll", Properties.Resources.MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor1);

                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\RSR\\WindowsFormsAero.dll", Properties.Resources.WindowsFormsAero);
            }
        }

        AssemblyName asm1 = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RSR\MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.dll");
        Assembly.Load(asm1);

        AssemblyName asm2 = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RSR\WindowsFormsAero.dll");
        Assembly.Load(asm2);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        using (_mainForm = new MainForm())
        {
            Application.Run(_mainForm);
        }

        Cursor normalCursor1 = new Cursor(new System.IO.MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.cursor_normal));
        SetSystemCursor(normalCursor1.Handle, 32512);
    }
```

Here is the following picture of the crash information when the 2 .dlls are not located within the same directory/path.

[image: READ COMMENT ABOVE]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have hard coded path that is pointing to your desktop; of course it will crash if the dlls are missing there. Why aren't you referencing them directly as "Add Reference..." in your solution. Shouldn't use Assembly.Load.

Comment: You can use my posted answer if you have to use embedded resource DLL.

Comment: Why in the world can't you just distribute the DLLs with your executable? Why do you need to embed them? This is going to cause all sorts of problems with virus scanners and security policies. Users should not have write permission to the app directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you must package your DLL as embedded resource you can load it through dynamic assembly resolve. Your code must run permission to load as well.

```
public static MainForm _mainForm;
{ 
  //Add this in your main initialization   
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve+=new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.Contains("FullNameSpace.MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor"))
    {
        return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor);
    }

    if (args.Name.Contains("FullNameSpace.MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor"))
    {
        return Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.WindowsFormsAero);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I can't embed these .dlls, the persistence option is locked to 'Linked at compile time'.

Comment: Didn't you already embed it in: Properties.Resources.WindowsFormsAero

Comment: The crash still happens; Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsFormsAero, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Your name space must match. Put breakpoint on the CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve and find out what is the namespace being requested for that assembly.

Comment: This is the breakpoint information; http://i.imgur.com/sdjQm69.png

This is what my resources looks like; http://i.imgur.com/fQ6velA.png

Comment: You aren't typing the code properly. I wrote "FullNameSpace" as an example. You have to replace that with correct namespace of the assembly that you are trying to load. Your resources are fine. The breakpoint will hit many times, as every assembly that would be requested would come to this method first. You want to look for args when it is your target assembly. I am guessing, you can shortcut this by just: args.Name.Contains("MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor")), and then args.Name.Contains("WindowsFormsAero")), without giving the full namespace; assuming actual namespace contains those words.